# queue of classes in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, queue

I'm attempting to create a queue of classes in c#. the queue implementation must use arrays. I know it's not the best option (I would've used lists, actually I would've used the queue class directly), but that's the requirement.

my question is:
let's say I have class A with properties x and y.
then I create the queue Q with a fixed number of 10 elements, and instantiate 10 instances of class A within.

now, if I want to for example print property y of instance Q[5], how do I need to proceed?

it should be something like Console.Writeline(Q[5].y) but the syntax is incorrect.

I haven't used c# in a while, so I'm sorry if it's a newbie question.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The method is `WriteLine`, and you need a semicolon at the end of the line:

```
Console.WriteLine(Q[5].y);
```